# Which kind of variable is more suitable?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, variables, radio-button

I’m going to build a GUI in MATLAB. This GUI page should do my settings.

I’ve six radio buttons, Camera One to Six. Under these radio buttons I’ve three additional radio buttons, Crop Side, and then under this section I’ve a Crop Percent slider.

What I want is, I need to select camera button five, for example, and then automatically set the latest setting that I’ve done on the radio buttons in Crop Side and Slider.
For example, once I’ve select the Camera Two button and set Crop Side to ‘Left’ and Crop Percent Slider to 12.

The next time I check it, the value of Crop side and Crop percent will be set to the ‘Left’ and 12, respectively. 
I don’t know which kind of variables and which syntax model would be more useful for this purpose.

Here are links to my code and figure:

https://www.4shared.com/account/home.jsp?sId=kcxzI7wiO9gxGRtq&changedir=-gDLNzzw
http://cdn.persiangig.com/download/GFJExIPKMO/Works.zip/dl

Comment: Please edit your post by adding a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

In your callback function for each button, include piece of code to save the buttons value and then load those values each time you choose a new camera, e.g. if you have click on camera 5 and then click on radiobutton for crop it could look something like this:

```
function radiobuttonCrop_Callback(hObject,event)
% <Here is the code you have atm>

% Add this code
load('guiSettings.mat')               % Loads a .mat file containing your settings 
settings.cam5.crop = get(hObject,'Value'); % Updates settings.crop to the current value
save('guiSettings.mat')               % Saves the updates
end
```

When you click on another camera, e.g. camera 3, load the settings for camera 3 as below:

```
function radiobuttonCamera3_Callback(hObject,handles)
load('guiSettings.mat')
set(handles.radiobuttonCrop,'Value',settings.cam3.Crop)
set(handles.slider,'Value',settings.cam3.Slider)
```

and so on.

Note: guiSettings.mat is the file name containing the settings. When loading with `load('guiSettings.mat')` you will get the variable `settings` contained in the file. `settings` is a struct containing all cameras and all settings for the cameras.

I hope this helps.